# How to select records with MAX Id that group by multiple columns in LINQ to SQL

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql, entity-framework-6

I need to select the last record of particular columns. I have the following records

```
WarehouseId | ItemId | SubItemId | DeliveryGroupId | Other Columns
     1      |   1    |     1     |        1        |      ...
     1      |   1    |     1     |        2        |      ...
     1      |   1    |     1     |        3        |      ...
     1      |   1    |     2     |        1        |      ...
     1      |   1    |     2     |        2        |      ...
     1      |   2    |     1     |        1        |      ...
```

Then I only want to select the MAX(DeliveryGroupId) for each `WarehouseId | ItemId | SubItemId`. The result should be:

```
WarehouseId | ItemId | SubItemId | DeliveryGroupId | Other Columns
     1      |   1    |     1     |        3        |      ...
     1      |   1    |     2     |        2        |      ...
     1      |   2    |     1     |        1        |      ...
```

In SQL, it is very simple to do:

```
SELECT *
FROM [dbo].[tblOrderDeliveryGroup] t1
WHERE [DeliveryGroupId] IN
(
    SELECT MAX([DeliveryGroupId])
    FROM [dbo].[tblOrderDeliveryGroup] t2
    WHERE (t1.[WarehouseId] = t2.[WarehouseId]) AND (t1.[ItemId] = t2.[ItemId]) AND (t1.[SubItemId] = t2.[SubItemId])
    GROUP BY [WarehouseId], [ItemId], [SubItemId]
);
```

The question is, how do I translate that SQL statement into LINQ-to-SQL?

Thanks

### UPDATE

So far, this is my solution. It is ***very*** ugly and surely ***not*** efficient.

```
var vLastRecs = (from rec in tblOrderDeliveryGroups.AsNoTracking()
                 group rec by new { rec.WarehouseId, rec.ItemId, rec.SubItemId } into grec
                 select new
                 {
                     grec.Key.WarehouseId,
                     grec.Key.ItemId,
                     grec.Key.SubItemId,
                     DeliveryGroupId = grec.Max(rec => rec.DeliveryGroupId)
                 });

return (from rec in tblOrderDeliveryGroups.AsNoTracking()
        where vLastRecs.Any(lrec => (rec.WarehouseId == lrec.WarehouseId) && (rec.ItemId == lrec.ItemId) && (rec.SubItemId == lrec.SubItemId) && (rec.DeliveryGroupId == lrec.DeliveryGroupId))
        select rec).ToList();
```

Is it possible to improve it?

Answer (score 0):

Try following :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Data;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            dt.Columns.Add("WarehouseId", typeof(int));
            dt.Columns.Add("ItemId", typeof(int));
            dt.Columns.Add("SubItemId", typeof(int));
            dt.Columns.Add("DeliveryGroupId", typeof(int));

            dt.Rows.Add(new object[] {1,1,1,1});
            dt.Rows.Add(new object[] {1,1,1,2});
            dt.Rows.Add(new object[] {1,1,1,3});
            dt.Rows.Add(new object[] {1,1,2,1});
            dt.Rows.Add(new object[] {1,1,2,2});
            dt.Rows.Add(new object[] {1,2,1,1});

            DataTable dt2 = dt.AsEnumerable()
                .OrderByDescending(x => x.Field<int>("DeliveryGroupId"))
                .GroupBy(x => new { warehouse = x.Field<int>("WarehouseId"), item = x.Field<int>("ItemId"), subitem = x.Field<int>("SubItemId")})
                .Select(x => x.FirstOrDefault())
                .CopyToDataTable();

        }
    }
}
```

---

Here is a solution using classes

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Data;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            OrderDeliveryGroups tblOrderDeliverGroups = new OrderDeliveryGroups();


            List<AsNoTracking> vLastRecs = tblOrderDeliverGroups.AsNoTracking() 
                .OrderByDescending(x => x.DeliverGroupId)
                .GroupBy(x => new { x.WarehouseId, x.ItemId, x.SubItemId})
                .Select(x => x.FirstOrDefault())
                .ToList();
        }
    }
    public class OrderDeliveryGroups
    {
        public List<AsNoTracking> AsNoTracking()
        {
            return new List<AsNoTracking>() {
                new AsNoTracking() { WarehouseId = 1, ItemId = 1, SubItemId = 1, DeliverGroupId = 1 },
                new AsNoTracking() { WarehouseId = 1, ItemId = 1, SubItemId = 1, DeliverGroupId = 2 },
                new AsNoTracking() { WarehouseId = 1, ItemId = 1, SubItemId = 1, DeliverGroupId = 3 },
                new AsNoTracking() { WarehouseId = 1, ItemId = 1, SubItemId = 2, DeliverGroupId = 1 },
                new AsNoTracking() { WarehouseId = 1, ItemId = 1, SubItemId = 2, DeliverGroupId = 2 },
                new AsNoTracking() { WarehouseId = 1, ItemId = 2, SubItemId = 1, DeliverGroupId = 1 }
            };
        }
    }
    public class AsNoTracking
    {
        public int WarehouseId { get; set; }
        public int ItemId { get; set; }
        public int SubItemId { get; set; }
        public int DeliverGroupId { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi jdweng, I want to select as List of `tblOrderDeliveryGroup` objects. Is this possible?

Comment: Yes.   Not sure what the issue is.  Looked at you updated code and that is what you are doing.  A Group is a two dimensional array : List<Key, List<object>>.  I usually crate a dictionary to look up : Dictionary<key, List<object>>.  It is very simple in linq to take my query and turn into a dictionary.

Comment: I think my code is very ugly and inefficient... are there any other more efficient way?

Comment: What is wrong with my method?  To remove the AND statement you would next to create a class that inherits IEquatable<T>

Comment: Hi jdweng, I am not sure how to implement your method to mine. If you see mine, it went on 2 loops. First, get the max `DeliveryGroupId` and then 2nd loop to see if the record matches these Ids. Therefore, essentially, it scans the table twice. I didn't say your method is wrong, I just don't know how to implement yours to get list of `tblOrderDeliveryGroup` objects. Also, I might be unclear on my question, I need linq-to-sql and not just linq. My sincere apology for the confusion.